# Generate Stationary Gaussian Series Data

Tags: r, time-series, gaussian

I want to simulate a time series data with mean `0` and covariance `cov(ui, uj) = p^2(j-i)^(-a)` and `a` is a constant.

```
p = 0.5
a = 3


covmat = matrix(NA, nrow = 2, ncol =  2)
for(i in 1: nrow(covmat)){
  for(j in 1: ncol(covmat)){
    covmat[i,] = p^2*(j-i)^(-a)
  }
}

covmat
```

Why I am getting `Inf` in the last row?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `p^2*(j-i)^(-a)`?

Comment: @NelsonGon, the `j` and `i` are the `column` and `row of the matrix cell respectively. And `p` and `a` are some known constant.

Comment: First, you need `covmat[i, j]`. Second, you get `Inf` when `i == j` as then the denominator is 0. Are you sure that's the autocovariance function that you need? If we restrict variances to `p^2`, then the first order autocovariances will be the same as variances. Perhaps it should be `p^2 / (1 + |i-j|)^a`?

Comment: @JuliusVainora. The `(j-i)` is in the numerator. I have  `p^2*(j-i)^(-a)`. I am generating the covariance matrix using this function.

Comment: @score324, `(j-i)^(-a)` with positive `a` puts `j-i` to the denominator.

Comment: @JuliusVainora. I got it. Thanks.